# O que significam aqueles 3 bytes iniciais, na resposta lida após método Open() da TIPClientHttp() da HbTip?

Tags: json, http, harbour

Quando chamo o método Read(), logo após um Open() da classe TIPClientHttp(), recebo uma string JSON vinda de uma página em PHP. Porém, notei que ocorre de vir, junto, três bytes de caracteres estranhos que precedem os dados desejados. O problema ocorre com um dado URL e com outro não.

Estou usando exemplos da HBTip que acompanham o Harbour 3.2, para tentar consumir uma API REST desenvolvida em PHP. A solução que encontrei para o problema foi suprimir esses três bytes iniciais, invocando a função substr(). Mas, gostaria de entender melhor a causa. Talvez, eu não esteja sabendo utilizar o método de forma correta. Pode ser, também, que o problema esteja na API.

Trecho de exemplo de meu código onde o problema acontece:

```
    oHTTP := TIPClientHttp():new( "http://localhost/api/index.php/clients" )
    oHTTP:setCookie(cSessaoAtiva)
    oHTTP:hFields := hAuthBearer
    if oHTTP:Open()
        cJSON := oHttp:read()
        cJSON := substr(cJSON,4) // Remove 3 bytes estranhos que aparecem 
                                // no início da string, quando lida logo
                                // depois do método Open().
        cSessaoAtiva := oHTTP:getcookies()
    else
        ? "Etapa #1 Error:", "oHTTP:Open()", oHTTP:lastErrorMessage()
    endif
```

[image: Demonstração dos três primeiros caracteres estranhos recebidos]

Comment: Talvez seja o [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Mas em tese o formato JSON recebe strings em ASCII com direito a escapes do índice do caracter especial na tabela UTF-16. Se for isso mesmo, o problema está no provedor da API que não deveria ter colocado isso em começo de conversa

Comment: É o BOM, mesmo. A página PHP que responde no único URL que está retornando esses caracteres estranhos estava formatada com o UTF-8 BOM. Salvei como UTF-8 sem BOM e resolveu o problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Sinceramente sugiro ficar longe da HBTip em produção. Vou "emprestar" as palavras do Viktor Szakats: _Due to the excessive amount of problem reports and long known problems and due to the non-trivial nature of internet protocols, this fork strongly recommends to avoid using this library in anything production or in fact anything more serious than simple test code for educational purposes (...) even if something happens to work in some specific scenario, it's highly likely it's not a stable solution, nor is it secure_ - E de fato é isso mesmo, a HBTip é praticamente "amarrada com arame"

Comment: Estou ciente do aviso do Viktor Szakats. Mas, em meus experimentos, usando a HBTIP, até o momento, ela tem se comportado bem, salvo uma exceção, e não encontrei alternativa rápida e fácil de começar a usar. Neste caso recente, em especial, o problema estava na página PHP da API que eu construí ou na formatação dos arquivos escrito em xBase. A página PHP estava salva no formato UTF-8 com BOM e retornava os três caracteres de marca de ordem de byte("byte order mark") ou, talvez, algo similar. Os arquivos xBase estavam salvos com UTF-8 sem BOM e trabalhando com mapa de caracteres no formato ASCII

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUO3a.jpg

Comment: @LuizDataprol destaque pro final que não colei aqui a toa kkk: _"even if something happens to work in some specific scenario, it's highly likely it's not a stable solution, nor is it secure"_. Note que é só uma recomendação, se quiser usar ela já está com você no pacote. Só comentei pra tentar evitar que você construa algo em cima dela pra depois se arrepender e ter que trocar de qq forma. prepare-se pra encontrar muitas exceções. Se for trabalhar com email um dia então, nem se fale. O que a HBTIP pode ser útil pra você é você olhar o fonte e aproveitar partes que interessam em código próprio.

Comment: @Bacco, eu tenho lido relatos, em fóruns de discussão de programação xBase, a respeitos de dificuldades e problemas da utilização da HBTIP. Não pretendo utilizá-la em produção, sabendo de que não funciona bem. Mas, fiquei curioso em testar os recursos e saber, na prática, o que funciona bem e o que não e quais seus motivos. Como você sugeriu, realmente, é possível aproveitar algumas partes da mesma, a princípio.

Comment: Até o momento, as transações HTTP, com minha API, usando HBTIP, por exemplo, sem SSL, tem funcionado. O problema que encontrei, nisso, foi tentar enviar strings JSON de dados, sem ter de inserir na URL, pelo método GET. Ele não aceita. Mas, como funciona, da mesma forma, pelo método OPEN, consegui contornar. Para meus estudos da viabilidade de uso, em paralelo, utilizo o Postman e comparo os comportamentos de ambos.

Comment: Não entendi bem. O GET é sempre pelo URL (tanto que normalmente GET não tem Body). Qualquer lib que faça envio de dados por GET no fim vai por os dados no path de qualquer jeito (mesmo que na lib você use uma função separada do URL)

Comment: Pois é. Foi o que também aprendi. Mas, como o Postman permite usar a área "body" para entrar com os dados JSON, afim de enviar por GET, achei que tivesse alguma maneira de enviar pelo corpo ou que, como você mesmo disse, ele enviasse por URL e que a HBTIP também fizesse isso.